# How to select only one number and get all there names

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

1. **Sample:** 1       BEEF 1      FRIED RICE 1        SPECIALTY BEEF 2 Kitchen 3 Dog
2. **Result:** **1**       BEEF,FRIED RICE,SPECIALTY BEEF **2** Kitchen **3** Dog

assuming **qno**(1) is the **number** and **Code**(beef) etc. is **names**
How to display one number and get all there names and return it in one div. I'm only using one div to display all the data. Thanks in advance. I know that this is easy for u guys but Im taking too long to code it...

```
 **Here is the javascipt.**
  success: function (data) {
        $('#scrollIncoming').empty();
        for (var i in data) {
            var rc = '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
            var qno = [data[i].QueueNo];
            for (var currentQueueNo = 0; currentQueueNo < qno.length; currentQueueNo++)
               $('#scrollIncoming').append(
                        '<span style="background-color:' + rc + ';width: 33%;border:1px solid black;height: 220px;float: left;">' +
                            '<span style="font-size: 60px;color:white; text-align: center;margin-top:30px;margin-left: 150px">' + qno[currentQueueNo] + '</span>' +
                            '<span style="font-size: 10px;width: 33%;text-align: center;color:black;margin-top:80px;margin-left: 80px">' +
                            data[i].Quantity + '&nbsp' + data[i].Code +
                            '<span style="font-size: 20px;width: 33%;text-align: center;margin-top:150px;margin-left: 50px">' +
                            '<img src="./resources/images/dispatch.png"/></a>' +
                            '<img src="./resources/images/dispatchingPage.png"/></a>' +
                            '<img src="./resources/images/undo.png"/></a>' + '</span>' +
                '<div id="div1">' +
                    '</div>'                   
                    );              
        $('#lblIncomingCounter').text(data.length);
        }
    }
**Here is the aspx.**
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div style="background-color: #ecf0f1; width: 100%; border: black 1px solid; margin: auto">
                <div id="scrollIncoming">
                    <div id='container'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>


**Here is the code behind**
listTransactions.Add(new ....()          {
    QueueNo = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["dd_queue_no"]),
    RefNo = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["key"]),
   Quantity =Convert.ToInt32(rdr["quantity"]),
   Code = Convert.ToString(rdr["name"]),
   OrderStatus = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[".."])
  });

 **Here is the sp**
@cluster int,
    @order_status int
..
 declare
    @datetoday datetime

    set @datetoday = CONVERT (date, GETDATE())

    select 
        DISTINCT (t.dd_queue_no),
        t.[key],
        p.name,
        pt.quantity,
        t.dd_order_status

    from 
        transactions t
    inner join 
        product_transactions pt
    on 
        t.[key] = pt.transactions_key
    inner join
        products p
    ON 
        pt.[products_key] = p.[key]
    where 
        t.dd_cluster_key = @cluster and t.dd_order_status = @order_status
    and
        t.[datetime]
    between 
        cast(@datetoday+' 00:00:00' as datetime) and cast(@datetoday+' 23:59:00' as datetime)
    order BY
         [dd_queue_no]
```

Comment: if you add a jsfiddle sample code you might get a better result.

Comment: Is your data coming for ASP.NET back end?

Comment: i dont have jsfiddle. yes back end

Comment: I think you can arrange data in your backend. tell me your listTransactions type

Comment: if possible I only need to do it in jscript.

Comment: if possible I only need to do it in jscript

Comment: I'll bet there is a LOT of code in there that's not entirely relevant to the problem. This sounds like an easy one to solve but I'm not reading through all of that. Reduce it to the parts that are relevant (i.e. where you're doing/failing on doing the grouping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var append = $('#scrollIncoming').append(
                              '<div  onclick="javascript:fnc' +
                              'UpdateStatus(' + data[j].RefNo + ',' + data[j].OrderStatus + ')">' +
                              '<div id="scrollIncoming' + data[j].QueueNo + '" class="mainDiv">' +
                              '<div class="mainDivHead"><span  class="detailsSpanHead">' + ata[j].QueueNo + '</span></div>' +
                              '<div id="innermo' + data[j].QueueNo + '" class="mainDivBody">' +
                              '<span class="detailsSpan">' + data[j].Quantity + ' - ' + data[j].Code + '</span></br>' +
                              '</div>' +
                              '</div>'
                                );
```

my apologies, late response.. by the way I already solved it. Thanks bdw